# PHP txt file edit Issue

Tags: php, mysql, text-files

Im trying to create a script that will post a notification stored in a text file when a project is created/updated.
If the project is created it needs to create the file and if the project is being updated it needs to update the existing txt file for it.

So far I've got it to create the txt file and update it. However it is only updating it once, if i try to update the file again it just doesn't do it.

Here's the code:

```
function addPost($userID, $content, $date, $featured, $projectID){
    if($projectID != 0){
        $addClass = 'normal';
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `projectID` = ".$projectID;
        $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
        $num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($query1);
        if($num_rows1 != 0){
            $addClass = 'internalUpdate';
        }
    }else{
        $addClass = 'normal';
    }

    switch($addClass){
    case normal;
        //SQL to get next ID
        $nameQuery = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `blog`");
        $nameRow = mysql_fetch_array($nameQuery);
        $nextID = $nameRow['MAX(ID)'] + 1;
        //Set Blogname
        $blogName = md5($nextID).'.txt';
        $blogTargetFile = './file/blog/'.$blogName;
        $fileHandle = fopen($blogTargetFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fileHandle, $content);
        fclose($fileHandle);
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `blog` (`userID`, `name`, `created`, `featured`, `projectID`) VALUES ('".$userID."', '".$blogName."', '".$date."', '".$featured."', '".$projectID."')";
    break;
    case internalUpdate;
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `projectID` = ".$projectID;
        $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
        $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
        $blogName = $row1['name'];
        $blogTargetFile = './file/blog/'.$blogName;
        $fileHandle = fopen($blogTargetFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fileHandle, $content);
        fclose($fileHandle);
        $sql2 = "UPDATE `blog` SET `created` = '".$date."' WHERE `ID` = ".$row1['ID'];
    break;
    }
    mysql_query($sql2);
};
```

An Ideas?

Charles - richini-design.co.uk

Comment: You have to narrow down the problem a little bit. Does the code enter proper `case` branch? If it does, is there any error raised?

Comment: Isn't it just a mistake on `case 'normal'; ... case 'internalUpdate';` (add text delimiters) ?

Comment: Can't see a problem there, thought the whole shuffle with the `ID` and `MD5` is a bit strange, you can first execute an insert statement and get the id with `mysql_insert_id()`. No need to hash the name as the identifier is already unique. I hope there's a reason as to why you store blog contents in a separate file (why not in the database?)

Comment: I've been an absolute idiot. One of those 2 days of re coding bits and bobs trying all sorts of different coding etc. when actually id just forgotten to call the function in the right bit of code :( Mega FAIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I got it right, but you're overwriting the file because of the "w" mode used with fopen function.
Try `fopen([filename], "a")` to append data.
See http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php for more infos.

Comment: I've been an absolute idiot. One of those 2 days of re coding bits and bobs trying all sorts of different coding etc. when actually id just forgotten to call the function in the right bit of code :( Mega FAIL